# Google Apps Script Web App: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

I am creating a Web App in Google Apps Script that have a server-side javascript file (Code.gs) and a client-side file (order-page-js.html). I am attempting to pull data from a spreadsheet, create an object, and send the object (which contains two key-value pairs, items and orders, both with two dimensional arrays as the values) from the server-side to the client-side so that it can populate data on the HTML web app . However, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at userCodeAppPanel:199:24
    at Of (2515706220-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:94:266)
    at 2515706220-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:25:132
    at Ug.U (2515706220-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:123:380)
    at Bd (2515706220-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:54:477)
    at a (2515706220-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:52:52)
```

Here is the server side code related to this issue:

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let itemsWS = ss.getSheetByName('Items');
  let items= itemsWS.getRange(2, 1, itemsWS.getLastRow()-1, itemsWS.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let ordersWS = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
  let orders= ordersWS.getRange(2, 1, ordersWS.getLastRow()-1, ordersWS.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  let res = {};

  res.items = items;
  res.orders = orders;

  return res;
```

Here is the client side showing where the error occurs. Line 199 (where the error occurs) is the `menuItems = Object.values(res.items);` line.

```
const order = new Order();

function sheetData(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(res) {

    menuItems = Object.values(res.items);
    orders = res.orders;

    order.menu = menuItems;
    order.previousOrders = orders;

    Ui.menu(order);
    Ui.orderNumber(order);
  }).getData();
}

sheetData();
```

I have been able to get the data from the spreadsheet without issue. I have been able to send just one of the key-value pairs (such as from the server-side to the client-side, but the object always has a value of `null` although I receive `object` when trying `console.log(typeof(res));`

When I `Logger.log(res);` on the server-side immediately before `return res;`, the object appears to have both key-value pairs with both values being the correct two-dimensional arrays. However, when I attempt to work with the object on the client-side, I receive the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error.

Comment: If any of the `items` or `orders` is a Date object you can not transmit a Date object to the client.  You need to stringify it first.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear why you are using `Object.values()` in the first place. What are you trying to accomplish by using it? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74659049/13045193) the question to add the explanation there.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you so much! the 0th array value for `orders` was indeed a date! Stringify did the trick.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]